# ssjs json object on marketing cloud does not show boolean value

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

This is very troubling as JSON object is behaving differently in SSJS than standard JavaScript. See the example below.

**Referencing by array index:**

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var payload={"HasOptedOutOfEmail":true,"HasOptedOutOfTxt":false}
Write("Payload begin <br />");
Write(payload['HasOptedOutofEmail']);
Write(payload['HasOptedOutofTxt']);
Write("Payload end <br />");

</script>
```

**Referencing by attribute name:**

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var payload={"HasOptedOutOfEmail":true,"HasOptedOutOfTxt":false}
Write("Payload begin <br />");
Write(payload.HasOptedOutofEmail);
Write(payload.HasOptedOutofTxt);
Write("Payload end <br />");

</script>
```

None of the above examples displays the boolean values in the two attributes. can someone confirmed that this is happening to them as well, or it is something i did wrong, perhaps suggest a way to work around the issue.

Comment: JavaScript is a case-sensitive language and it looks like the word `of` (lowercase `o`) in `payload['HasOptedOutofEmail']` does not match the case used in your object property declaration (`"HasOptedOutOfEmail"`, uppercase `O`). The same goes for `"HasOptedOutOfTxt"`. I would correct that first then see if you're still having issues.

Comment: thanks. it was indeed case sensitivity issue.